# 'missing initializer for member' for std::string_view member

Tags: c++, c++20, aggregate-initialization

I thought I understood how struct initialization worked. But apparently not. Here's an innocuous looking struct:

```
struct Foo {
  int a = 0;
  std::string_view b;
};

Foo bar() {
  return {.a = 47};  // error: missing initializer for member 'Foo::b'
}
```

I mean, why? Even stranger is that the following fixes the 'error':

```
struct Foo {
  int a = 0;
  std::string_view b = "";  // Huh?
};
```

I thought that `std::string_view` has default initialization so need to explicitly assign it the empty string. I'm obviously missing something here, but not clear what ...

UPDATE:

Like all good shops, we compile with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra`. All warnings are errors ... as they should be!

Comment: Compiles fine with gcc13. Which compiler are you using? Perhaps you are using the -Wpedantic -Werror flags?

Comment: Can't reproduce with multiple compilers on compiler explorer either.

Comment: Perhaps your compiler is (mis?)configured to treat warnings as errors? This should be a warning at most.

Comment: Please do include the full error message and/or exact compiler version and configuration, as required for [mcve].

Comment: Compiler: gcc-12-arm64-linux. Error message: missing initializer for member 'Foo::b' [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]

Comment: IIRC, when you use designated initializers, all members *must* be initialized, one way or another. You can not leave out a member. By doing inline initialization that requirement is fulfilled.

Comment: @LajosNagy `[-Werror=missing-field-initializers]` means that this is a warning that you intentionally elevated to a fatal error. You gave the compiler some flags such as `-Wextra -Werror`. `-Werror` implies that the compiler will not accept some code that is actually valid C++, such as is the case here.

Comment: I guess what I'm not getting is why adding ` = ""` after `b` in the struct changes anything. I thought you don't need to explicitly initialize `std::string_view`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about the std::string_view, you would get the same warning for the following piece of code:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    std::string_view b;
};

Foo bar() {
    return {.b = ""};  // error: missing initializer for member 'Foo::a'
}
```

This is the compiler's way of telling you that you might have forgotten to explicitly initialize the other struct fields.
This warning is enabled with -Wextra, If you'd like to keep this option and disable only the missing initializer warning, you can use [-Wno-missing-field-initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-field-initializers).

Comment: 1. You have changed the structure definition. 2. `std::string_view` has the default constructor that constructs an empy `std::string_view`.